# Why does $\lim\limits_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{f(x + 2 \Delta x) - f(x)}{\Delta x} = 2 f'(x)$?

Tags: calculus

This is an exercise from Morris Kline's "Calculus: An Intuitive and Physical Approach":

> What is $\lim\limits_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{f(x + 2 \Delta x) - f(x)}{\Delta x}$?
> *Suggestion:* Let $2 \Delta x = t$

Following the hint, we have

\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{f(x + 2 \Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x} &=\lim\limits_{t \to 0} \frac{f(x + t)-f(x)}{t/2} \\
 &= \lim\limits_{t \to 0} 2 \left (  \frac{f(x + t)-f(x)}{t} \right) \\
&= 2 \left ( \lim\limits_{t \to 0}   \frac{f(x + t)-f(x)}{t} \right) \\
&= 2 f'(x)
\end{align}

I'm not fully understanding why this is true. Wouldn't it depend on the function we are differentiating? How can we be sure that increasing the change in $x$ will increase the instantaneous rate of change of in $f(x)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation is fine. For an intuition, we are considering the variation of the variable for the function $2\Delta x$ twice the variation of the variable $\Delta x$ therefore the result we obtain is twice the derivative at that point.

More in general

$$\lim\limits_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{f(x + n \Delta x) - f(x)}{\Delta x}=\lim\limits_{n\Delta x \to 0} n\frac{f(x + n \Delta x) - f(x)}{n\Delta x}=nf'(x)$$

Comment: So basically the instantaneous rate of change increases by a factor of $n$ since we increased how much the function varies by a factor of $n$ while keeping the interval of variation the same ($\Delta x$)?

Comment: @Iyeeke Yes exactly that's the reason why we obtain $nf'(x)$.

Comment: I see, thank you!